# Changing the Label1.Text of Form1 from Form2 Button1_Click in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change the `Label1.Text` on my `Form1` (owner) by `Button1_Click` triggered from `Form2`, but there are no changes on `Label1.Text`. It is still empty string (""). I have double/triple checked my code. I could not find anything wrong.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
Form1
    // Label1 is inside the TabControl Page 0
    // Label1.Modifier property already set to public
    // and Label1.Text = ""

    public static FrmOwner Self;

    public FrmOwner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Self = this;        
    }

    private void Button2_Click()
    {
        FrmForm2 frm = new FrmForm2 ();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

Form2
    public FrmForm2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmOwner.Self.Label1.Text = "Changed Text";
    }
```

I am sure there's something wrong with my code, definitely. Please help.

Comment: frm.ShowDialog(); Have you tried it with just frm.Show();??

Comment: @JosipJuros Yes, I've tried but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. Passing the form or the control/variable you want to access is probably the best approach as it does not unnecessarily expose the passed control/variable and everything can be kept private.

However, this can be simplified if you choose to expose the control/variable in the first form. In this example it appears that the `Label` control `label1` in form1 is what we want to have access to in form2. Therefore, a very simple approach is to take advantage of the `Forms` `Owner` property and it should work as described below.

First, we want to expose form1’s `Label`… `label1` control by setting its `Modifier` property to `public`.

Then when `Form1` creates and shows `Form2`… we want to pass `Form1` to `Form2` by taking advantage of the `Forms` `Owner` property which is done by simply passing the `Owner` form to `Form2` when `Form2`’s `Show` or `ShowDialog` is called. Something like below….

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show(this);
```

Note the `this` as a parameter when calling the `Show/ShowDialog` method. This is all we need to do in the first form. The parameter `this` in the `Show/ShowDialog` will set the called forms `Owner` property to a generic `Form` which we can later cast to a `Form1` object in the called form.

Then in the second `Form2` when we want to get access to `Form1`s `publicly` exposed `label1`… we simply have to cast form2’s `Owner` property to a `Form1` object since the `Owner` is a “generic” `Form` object. So, this would look something like…

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ((Form1)Owner).label1.Text = "Hello from form2";
}
```

That is all that is needed.

Comment: Glad to help. It should be noted that, technically, we are taking advantage to the `Forms` `Owner` property and this is certainly convenient. However, we are basically passing way more than we need. We really only need the `Label` and we are passing the whole `Form`… so it’s like bringing a whole Home Depot store to your house so you can buy a hammer. IMO, passing the `Label` to the other form through its constructor is the best approach but it does require a few more lines of code.

Comment: Does it has implications or heavy overheads if I want to bring the entire depot store rather than the hammer only? I am saying this because my development requires interactions between forms from time to time. For convenience and speedy development I prefer home depot instead of hammer, unless otherwise, it cost more than the benefit I am looking at.

Comment: Technically, the overhead is minimal as I am pretty sure a reference is the only thing passed. Its more along the lines of exposing “everything” that is public in `form1` to `form2` which breaks some basic OOP principles. But I am in your “convenience” camp… give me the whole store even if I only want the hammer. 

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Form1 instance to Form2. Then access From1 public methods and properties from From2.

**Form1**

```
public static FrmOwner Self;

public FrmOwner()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Self = this;        
}

private void Button2_Click()
{
    FrmForm2 frm = new FrmForm2 (this);
    frm.ShowDialog();
}

public void SetLabel(string txt)
{
   Label1.Text = txt
}
```

**Form2**

```
private FrmForm1 _frm1;

public FrmForm2(FrmForm1 frm1)
{
    _frm1 = frm1;

    InitializeComponent();      
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _frm1.SetLabel("New Text");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! This approach I've been using for accessing the method. I did not realize that there's a workaround for properties. However, I've used the same approach in my case here in my other form and it is working. There only difference is I am using Label inside the TabControl and in my other code, I am using StatusStrip. For now, I'll mark this as the answer but I still want to know what's wrong with my code above.

Comment: @RickyBelmont: I am not too sure why static instance way is not working for you. You can try calling a public method and put a breakpoint to see if it actually hit, just out of curiosity. However, I think this solution is better than having public/static instances.

Comment: I agree this seems better. I will make this my standard in all my parent/child forms interactions. But I still try to check your suggestion. Thanks again! So kind of you.

Comment: @CharithJ - this isn't the standard way to do this. Normally you'd just expose an event on `Form2` that `Form1` attaches to.

Answer (score 1):

I've been following with interest, and of the answers so far the one I most agree with is Enigmativity but I feel it doesn't go far enough to decouple the `Form2` implementation from that of `Form1`. My suggestion is something closer to the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) design model which one could use to make the code more maintainable and portable (e.g. taking the long view that we might want to make iOS and Android versions of this app someday).

Consider this `Form2` that has two (so far) bindable properties `Visible` and `BindableText` and sends a notification when either one changes. The `Button` on `Form2` now acts upon the `BindableText` property when clicked.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Form2() => InitializeComponent();

    private void buttonChangeText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        BindableText = $"Clicks = {_count++}";

    static int _count = 1;

    string _BindableText = string.Empty;
    public string BindableText
    {
        get => _BindableText;
        set
        {
            if(!Equals(_BindableText, value))
            {
                _BindableText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Visible && (Owner != null))
        {
            Location = new Point(
                Owner.Location.X + Owner.Width + 10,
                Owner.Location.Y
            );
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Visible));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, the simplified version of the main form `Form1` might look something like this:

[image: form 1]

When the checkbox goes true, the `PropertyChanged` event is attached before the new instance is shown. Then, similar to JohnG's answer, we call `ShowDialog(owner: this)` to assign the `Owner` property. In the `OnVisibleChanged` override, its `Location` is used to set the relative position for the popup when shown.

```
private void checkBoxShowForm2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
    {
        using (var form2 = new Form2())
        {
            form2.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                switch (e.PropertyName)
                {
                    case nameof(form2.BindableText):
                        label1.Text = form2.BindableText;
                        break;
                    case nameof(form2.Visible):
                        checkBoxShowForm2.Checked = form2.Visible;
                        checkBoxShowForm2.Enabled = !form2.Visible;
                        break;
                }
            };
            form2.ShowDialog(owner: this);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: relative position and button clicks]

`Form1` responds in the manner it sees fit when the properties change:

- Set the`Text` property of `private label1` when `BindingText` changes
- Unchecks the `private checkBoxShowForm2` when the `Visible` property goes false.

But, importantly, `Form1` will be unaffected if `Form2` has future changes to their internal implementation details.

---

**NOTE: Form2 requires disposal**

The CharithJ and Enigmativity answers would benefit from a `using` statement to prevent the resource leak in the `ShowDialog` calls. The official Microsoft documentation for  [Form.ShowDialog Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) states that a using block (or other dispose method) is required here:

> Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead of closed, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

It's designed this way so that `Form2` *could* be moved and instead of being a a *local* variable it could be *member*, instantiated once, and shown-closed multiple times. Such a thing is possible *because* it doesn't dispose its `Handle` (which would still need to be disposed when `Form1` does). But since it's currently being used as a local, it needs the `using`.

On the other hand, JohnG's use of `Show(this)` on a local new instance of `Form2` *will* dispose the handle but *will not* be modal. That is, it *will* stay on top of its owner `Form1` in the Z-order but *will not* prevent user interaction with `Form1`.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/show-dialog-with-property-change-notifications.git) this example.

Comment: As usual you're quite detail but broad with your answer, appreciate that. I agree with you that @Inigmativity looks the better answer but I am not saying the others are not. What I am saying is this post is a good resource for this type of case which is common to newbie like me. Others also may explore all the inputs provided here including yours. Thanks for the clone.

Comment: _newbie_ you say?? You ask pretty good questions for a _newbie_ and seem to have a talent for extracting what you need from variety of answers so, you may have already graduated.

Comment: Hahaha... Thank you! Didn't realize that. I am not an IT related profession but a trying hard one. No IT basic background but relies only on research, ability to logically analyze different programming syntaxes, and most of my resources comes here at `Stackoverflow University` especially from you guys, my Professors!

Answer (score 0):

The more idiomatic way to do this is with events.

FrmForm1

```
public class FrmForm1 : Form
{
    private void Button2_Click()
    {
        FrmForm2 frm = new FrmForm2();
        frm.LabelUpdated += FrmForm2_LabelUpdated;
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void FrmForm2_LabelUpdated(object sender, string txt)
    {
        Label1.Text = txt
    }
}
```

FrmForm2

```
public class FrmForm2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<string> LabelUpdated;

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.LabelUpdated?.Invoke(this, "New Text");
    }
}
```